# Same value in two columns of same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this table

```
    NAME           TYPE 
   codigo        numeric
   referencia    varchar 

   codigo         referencia
    3018        7898379460494
    3062        7897840302639          
    3064        7897840300154
```

i want to write a select like this :

```
    select CODIGO, REFERENCIA, DESCRICAO  from ESTOQUE where CODIGO like REFERENCIA
```

to know if have rows where codigo and reference have the same value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select CODIGO, REFERENCIA, DESCRICAO  
from ESTOQUE 
where convert(varchar(max),CODIGO) = REFERENCIA
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
select CODIGO, REFERENCIA, DESCRICAO  from ESTOQUE
    where convert(varchar, CODIGO) = REFERENCIA
```

Comment: You really should kick that habit of declaring `varchar` without a length :) https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: Yup, true - I copied the original question a bit too closely, in my own code it would have had one!

Answer (score 0):

```
select CODIGO, REFERENCIA, DESCRICAO  from ESTOQUE where CODIGO = cast(ESTOQUE.REFERENCIA as varchar(max))
```

Comment: @Barry Sorry, Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all

```
          select CODIGO, REFERENCIA, DESCRICAO  
         from ESTOQUE 
         where convert(varchar(max),CODIGO) = REFERENCIA
```

thas code work perfect.